# Date Difference between first (min) date with next consecutive dates till end of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

My base table with following structure

```
  ID            DC_NO           DC_DATE     NOB    TAG_NO
110168  DC/NGO/270118/188   1/27/18 0:00    800  NGO/191217/17
110169  DC/NGO/270118/189   1/27/18 0:00    400  NGO/191217/17
110170  DC/NGO/270118/190   1/27/18 0:00    600  NGO/191217/17
110171  DC/NGO/270118/192   1/27/18 0:00    700  NGO/191217/17
110172  DC/NGO/270118/196   1/27/18 0:00    720  NGO/191217/17
110173  DC/NGO/290118/179   1/29/18 0:00    700  NGO/191217/17
110174  DC/NGO/290118/227   1/29/18 0:00    500  NGO/191217/17
110175  DC/NGO/300118/220   1/30/18 0:00    834  NGO/191217/17
110176  DC/NGO/300118/221   1/30/18 0:00    600  NGO/191217/17
110177  DC/NGO/300118/221   1/30/18 0:00    10   NGO/191217/17
110178  DC/NGO/020218/185   2/2/18 0:00     900  NGO/191217/17
110179  DC/NGO/020218/186   2/2/18 0:00     3    NGO/191217/17
110180  DC/NGO/050218/176   2/5/18 0:00     50   NGO/191217/17
110181  DC/NGO/050218/177   2/5/18 0:00     29   NGO/191217/17
110182  DC/NGO/050218/177   2/5/18 0:00     24   NGO/191217/17
110183  DC/NGO/060218/105   2/6/18 0:00     56   NGO/191217/17
```

My probable output table should be like this

```
DAY    DC_DATE      NOB   ME
1    1/27/18 0:00   800   800
1    1/27/18 0:00   400   400
1    1/27/18 0:00   600   600
1    1/27/18 0:00   700   700
1    1/27/18 0:00   720   720
3    1/29/18 0:00   700   2100
3    1/29/18 0:00   500   1500
4    1/30/18 0:00   834   3336
4    1/30/18 0:00   600   2400
4    1/30/18 0:00   10    40
7    2/2/18 0:00    900   6300
7    2/2/18 0:00    3     21
10   2/5/18 0:00    50    500
10   2/5/18 0:00    29    290
10   2/5/18 0:00    24    240
11   2/6/18 0:00    56    616
           TOTAL   6926  20563
```

I want to allocate value for first dc_date should be 1xNOB (1x800=800) and second dc_date should be 3xNOB (3x700=2100) and third dc_date should be 4xNOB (4x834=3336) and so on till end of the table.

If dc_date is being changed then DAY value should be, second date-first date+1 (e.g. 29.01.18-27.01.18=2+1=3) and then third date-first date+1 (e.g. 30.01.18-27.01.18=3+1=4) and this process is goes on till end of the table

**first(MIN) date is base date and always value 1 and add this value after subtracting between two dates (e.g. 29.01-27.01=2+1, 30.01-27.01=3+1, 02.02-27.01=6+1, 05.02-27.01=9+1, 06.02-27.01=10+1)

The output that I required through query is "Total ME"=20563 and "Average ME"=2.969 (ME/ NOB) for the Base table mentioned above.

I don’t want to update the base table. Please use CTE query.

Group by should be on DC_DATE and TAG_NO. When TAG_NO changed then DAY value should be start from beginning once again. NOB field should be summed.

I am using sql server 2012

Comment: what did you try? where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
SELECT  
    DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(DC_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY TAG_NO), DC_DATE) + 1 DAY
    , DC_DATE
    , NOB
    , (DATEDIFF(DAY, MIN(DC_DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY TAG_NO), DC_DATE) + 1) * NOB AS ME
FROM [MyTable]
```

Comment: output of this query is "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near 'order'." . are you mean by FIRST_VALUE(DC_DATE)=MIN(DC_DATE)

Comment: you can also use MIN instead of FIRST_VALUE for this case